# Is there any way I can execute an external application from within MongoDB mapreduce?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

My aim is to call an external application, i.e. execute a Windows command line, from within the reduce function of a MongoDB mapreduce algorithm.

Is this possible using the V8 JS engine used by MongoDB 2.4+?

Or, in other terms, is there any other supported language for mapreduce in MongoDB?

Thanks a lot for answering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not possible to run another program from Map Reduce.

No there is not any other supported language, here is a JIRA for it: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-699